# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist when nesting data in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serialize a model with nested data for its relationships. The data is returned properly in a GET request but when trying to POST data the following error is returned: `api.models.Narration.narrative.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Narration has no narrative.` I have no interest in POSTing nested data, it only needs to be returned in the GET requests and PKs can be used everywhere else. I have tried to using `Meta.depth` as well as defining the fields manually, both of which return the same exception. Code is below, any help is appreciated.

```py
# serializers.py
class NarrationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    narrative = NarrativeSerializer(read_only=True)
    settings = MapSettingsSerializer(read_only=True)
    attached_events = CachedDataSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Narration
        fields = "__all__"
        # depth = 1 [also doesn't work]

# models.py
class Narration(OrderedModel):
    narrative = models.ForeignKey(Narrative, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    date_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    map_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    attached_events = models.ManyToManyField(CachedData)
    img = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    video = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    settings = models.ForeignKey(MapSettings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    order_with_respect_to = "narrative"

# views.py
class NarrationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Narration.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NarrationSerializer
```

POSTed nested data (using PKs results in same exception):

```
{
  "title": "cvxcv",
  "description": "cxvxcv",
  "date_label": "test",
  "map_datetime": "0002-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "img": "",
  "video": "",
  "narrative": {
    "author": "Test Author",
    "title": "Test Narrative",
    "description": "This is a test narrative.",
    "tags": [
      "test",
      "tags"
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "bbox": {
      "type": "MultiPoint",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          0,
          0
        ],
        [
          1,
          1
        ]
      ]
    },
    "zoom_min": 1,
    "zoom_max": 12
  },
  "attached_events": [
    {
      "event_type": 178561,
      "wikidata_id": 1,
      "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          0,
          0
        ]
      },
      "date": "0001-01-01",
      "rank": 830700
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can provide more info for the question.

Comment: @Nikhil Gupta what info in particular?

Comment: As they are related to your `Narration` model, so you need to POST the nested data.

Comment: why do you have `read_only=True` for the `narrative` field?

Comment: @Manzurul Hoque Rumi POSTing nested data returns the same exception.

Comment: Can you post how you posting nested data?

Comment: @Arpit Svt I was trying to only return nested data in a GET request, leaving PKs to be used for a POST, though that isn't a hard requirement.

Comment: @Manzurul Hoque Rumi question has been updated to show POSTed nested data

Comment: post your view code, and remove all three nested from serializer and manage those in view code only. `narrative = NarrativeSerializer(read_only=True)`
    `settings = MapSettingsSerializer(read_only=True)`
   ` attached_events = CachedDataSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)` Need to remove these three.

Comment: @Anup Yadav views.py added; how do you manage the display of fields in views.py?